# CORS как разрешить?

Tags: php, ajax, cors

Есть webview приложение, есть сервер на котором лежат php файлы, хочу с помощью AJAX запроса обращаться к php файлу на сервере, а браузер как вы понимаете не хочет, так вот как мне быть?

Везде пишут что нужно написать header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); Но куда это писать непонятно, никаких .htaccess в корне сервера я не нашел.

---

Вот пример php файла

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require "db.php"; //Подключение бд и рб

$data = $_POST;
$errors = array();

if (R::count('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login'])) > 0 ) {
  $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином уже существует!';
}
if (R::count('users', 'email = ?', array($data['email'])) > 0 ) {
  $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким email уже существует!';
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    $user = R::dispense('users');
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->surname = $data['surname'];
    $user->login = $data['login'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $user->start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    R::store($user);
}
else{
  echo array_shift($errors);
}
?>
```

Comment: Так в php-файле и писать

Comment: @andreymal написал, не работает

Comment: Не там написали значит

Comment: @andreymal Подскажите пожалуйста, куда именно надо написать

Comment: В том файле, для которого нужен доступ, в самом начале перед любым выводом данных

Comment: @andreymal писал и перед `<php?`  и сразу после, ничего не меняется все также "Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован"

Comment: Откройте мониторинг сети в браузере и посмотрите, какой ответ от сервера приходит и есть ли в ответе этот заголовок